# Stuck in Mean Stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, ubuntu, express

I am new to MEAN Stack. and i am using Ubuntu. i installed ejs, express, node etc via Terminal. i made a folder in Documents>NodeTuts and then in in terminal i wrote npm init after the progress i got package.json in nodeTuts and server.js and than i made a folder in nodeTuts named client and then in client>views and in views i made a file index.ejs.
In server.js i wrote:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var port = process.env.PORT;
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'views'));
app.get('/', function (req, res){
  res.render('index.ejs');
});
app.listen(port, function (){
  console.log('SERVER RUNNING... PORT: ' + port);
})`
```

and in index.js i wrote:
simply HELLO WORLD
but when i opened server.js in Chrome i thought there will be HELLO WORLD but there was server.js code as a text [This is what i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GjmR.png)
I am learning from Brent Aureli's Tutorials. he is doing all this on windows usng cloudy and i am doing this on Ubuntu!
Please help me It's been 3 days i am stuck in this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You must run `server.js` via `node` command like this:

```
PORT=8080 node server.js
```

Since you haven't specified port on your server file, you must write it with your `node` command.

Then, open Chrome and type into address bar `localhost:8080` (or other port).

---

If you don't want to write port every time you run `node` command, change this line:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080 // or any other port number
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! but as you said that change that line, i changed that then when i wrote "PORT=8080 node server.js" in terminal i got :module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/fasihmohammad/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
and when i wrote localhost:8080 in chrome it said localhost refused to connect. :(

Comment: @FasihShahzad You must cd to the folder, where the server.js file is.

Comment: @FasihShahzad If I or someone else helped you, consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), this will help others to see if a problem has been solved.